# ¿Cómo exportar el contenido de un DataFrame intercalando sus filas por un factor xx (determinado)?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo mis datos estructurados asi con la primera columna que es el ID principal y necesito exportar el contenido de mi DataFrame pero no correlativo como está de forma normal
así:

```
1| 3 8 16 39 82
2| 3 8 39 54 82
3| 3 8 39 82 89
4| 3 8 39 82 84
5| 3 8 39 49 82
6| 3 8 32 39 82
7| 3 7 8 39 82
8| 3 8 11 39 82
9| 3 8 39 43 82
10| 3 8 39 82 85
11| 3 8 39 77 82
12| 3 8 39 45 82
```

Sino intercalando la salida de las filas por una valor dado ejemplo valor de intercalado = 4 debería obtener una salida como esta:

```
1| 3 8 16 39 82
4| 3 8 39 82 84
7| 3 7 8 39 82
10| 3 8 39 82 85
2| 3 8 39 54 82
5| 3 8 39 49 82
8| 3 8 11 39 82
11| 3 8 39 77 82
3| 3 8 39 82 89
6| 3 8 32 39 82
9| 3 8 39 43 82
12| 3 8 39 45 82
```

La lógica seria empezar del 1ro. (1) y saltar 4 posiciones (4) y así hasta completar 4 iteraciones y luego se sigue del 2do. (2) y salta 4 (5) ....

Ojalá me haya expresado bien por que me urge solucionar esto y me estoy rompiendo el bocho

Asi tengo armado la salida del archivo CSV en mi dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(salida)
#INSERTA UNA COL. EN EL DATAFRAME CON LOS INDICES Y SEPARADOR
df.insert(loc=0,column='x',value=sepa)
#ESTABLECE EL INDICE Q COMIENCE DE 1
df.index= [_ for _ in range(1,len(df)+1)]
#GENERA EL FILE
df.to_csv(file, header=None , sep=' ', index=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo `df` es el siguiente dataframe:

```py
    x  1  2   3   4   5
1   |  3  8  16  39  82
2   |  3  8  39  54  82
3   |  3  8  39  82  89
4   |  3  8  39  82  84
5   |  3  8  39  49  82
6   |  3  8  32  39  82
7   |  3  7   8  39  82
8   |  3  8  11  39  82
9   |  3  8  39  43  82
10  |  3  8  39  82  85
11  |  3  8  39  77  82
12  |  3  8  39  45  82
```

Puedes crear el dataframe y el fichero "intercalado" así:

```py
import pandas as pd

intercalado = pd.concat([df.iloc[0::3, :], df.iloc[1::3, :], df.iloc[2::3, :]])
intercalado.to_csv('intercalado.csv', header=None, sep=' ')
```

El fichero sería:

```
1 | 3 8 16 39 82
4 | 3 8 39 82 84
7 | 3 7 8 39 82
10 | 3 8 39 82 85
2 | 3 8 39 54 82
5 | 3 8 39 49 82
8 | 3 8 11 39 82
11 | 3 8 39 77 82
3 | 3 8 39 82 89
6 | 3 8 32 39 82
9 | 3 8 39 43 82
12 | 3 8 39 45 82
```

Con un hueco en forma de parámetro:

```py
hueco = 5
intercalado = pd.concat([df.iloc[start::hueco, :] for start in range(hueco)])
intercalado.to_csv('intercalado.csv', header=None, sep=' ')
```

Resultando en el siguiente fichero

```
1 | 3 8 16 39 82
6 | 3 8 32 39 82
11 | 3 8 39 77 82
2 | 3 8 39 54 82
7 | 3 7 8 39 82
12 | 3 8 39 45 82
3 | 3 8 39 82 89
8 | 3 8 11 39 82
4 | 3 8 39 82 84
9 | 3 8 39 43 82
5 | 3 8 39 49 82
10 | 3 8 39 82 85
```

Si he entendido bien la nueva pregunta, lo siguiente funcionaria:

```py
N = len(df)
bonos_por_hoja = 4
if N % bonos_por_hoja != 0 and (N + 1) % bonos_por_hoja != 0:
    # si N no es un multiple de bonos_por_hoja y tampoco uno menos de un multiple,
    # añade un par the bonos vacios para que cada hajo tendrá suficientes bonos
    df = df.reindex(range(1, (N // bonos_por_hoja + 1) * bonos_por_hoja))
hueco = (len(df) + 1) // bonos_por_hoja
intercalado = pd.concat([df.iloc[start::hueco, :] for start in range(hueco)])
intercalado.to_csv('intercalado.csv', header=None, sep=' ')
```

Comment: Ahora me funciona esto pero me va dando un salto de forma indefinida por el valor establecido en hueco  y no debiera ser asi ..hueco = 4
    intercalado = pd.concat([df.iloc[start::hueco, :] for start in range(hueco)])
    intercalado.to_csv('intercalado.csv', header=None, sep=' ', index=None)

Comment: No entiendo que quieres decir exactamente con "salto de forma indefinida". ¿Tal vez podrías [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/524184/edit) la pregunta y añadir lo que has intentado, conjunto con el resultado?

Comment: Creo que está bien explicado la consulta. Si mirás atentamente el 2do bloque de codigo de como debería ser la salida del archivo veras que no es un salto de 4 del principio al fin sino cada que itera 4 y vuelve a la segunda fila y de alli comienza otra vez.

Comment: En definitiva tal vez ayude a entender que si tengo 12 registros y quiero imprimir 4 por hoja no debiera salir en la primera hoja el 1,2,3,4  sino el el 1,4,7,10 en la segunda hoja el 2,5,8,11 y ese es rl criterio cosa que al terlinar de imprimir tengo 3 hojas y corto los 4 bonos y ya me quedan apilados y no hay que intercalar a mano. Obvio este es un ejemplo pequeño tengo q trabajar con milesss

Comment: ¿Qué sería el resultado cuando tendrías 30 registros? ¿O 8? ¿O 5? ... Nota que `1,4,7,10`  tiene un salto de `3`.  Un salto de `4` seria `1,5,9`

Comment: ¿Como le va la nueva versión de la respuesta?

Comment: N = len(df)
bonos_por_hoja = 4
if N % bonos_por_hoja != 0 and (N + 1) % bonos_por_hoja != 0:
    # si N no es un multiple de bonos_por_hoja y tampoco uno menos de un multiple,
    # añade un par the bonos vacios para que cada hajo tendrá suficientes bonos
    df = df.reindex(range(1, (N // bonos_por_hoja + 1) * bonos_por_hoja))
hueco = (len(df) + 1) // bonos_por_hoja
intercalado = pd.concat([df.iloc[start::hueco, :] for start in range(hueco)])
intercalado.to_csv('intercalado.csv', header=None, sep=' ')

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/524194/152279   Es exactamente lo que necesitaba!!! Gracias capo me salvaste el finde !!!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135091/discussion-between-el-pibe-bazooka-and-johanc).

Comment: Hola, te molesto porque me funciona perfecto pero hay un detalle que no entiendo como resolverlo y es que me da al principio el separador y debiera ser a partir del segundo elemento  asi es como sale 1|,4,11,25 y asi es como debiera ser 1|4,11,25
.SEguro es una pavada pero te juro que no le encuentro la vuelta. Gracias